# Javascript - How to detect image request from an image element which is created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, xmlhttprequest

Basically, I use a Javascript Library which has this code under a function:

```
var img = new Image();   // Create new img element
img.src = 'URL/myImage.png'; // Set source path
```

It will send multiple HTTP GET requests to server (in Firefox's Developer Console > Network, their type is **'img'** under 'Cause' column).

How can I detect the event (image starts loading and image loaded completely) from the code above in my index.html using the javascript library (**I cannot change the library**)?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by listening to the **onloadstart** and **onload** events respectively.

```js
function ready() {
  console.log("picture loaded");
}

function started() {
  console.log("loading");
}
var img = new Image();
img.onload = ready;
img.onloadstart = started;
img.src = "https://picsum.photos/200/300";
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not what I asked (I cannot change the library) to add event to the created image element.

Comment: That depends on your library. If it exposes these images as global variables it might be possible but we would need to see what library you're talking about.

Comment: I think it is not possible as the image variables created inside the function of the library, thanks anyway.